# AWS Elastic Beanstalk HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, dns, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can code but I don't understand anything about servers or DNS settings.

I found I could easily use beanstalk to launch applications that I'm working on but I do not understand fully how to properly create DNS entries and enable HTTPS.

In Route 53 I was able to successfully create a "Hosted Zone", point my domain to amazons four name servers, and create two A records. I created an A record for "domain.tld" and "www.domain.tld" and for each I selected "yes" for alias and "yes" for evaluate target health. For each A record for the alias I entered the long "environment.key.region2.elastickbeanstalk.com" URL they gave me for the application I created in Beanstalk.

To my surprise everything worked and visiting domain.tld or www.domain.tld goes to the root index.php file. Is there a better way to do this? I'm not sure if what I did is the correct way to do this.

Also, part two of my question: How do I setup HTTPS? - I watched a YouTube video where the guy goes to Services > Certificate Manager enters in "*.domain.tld" which I did, selected DNS validation, created a CNAME record as it requested me to do, the status updates successfully to "issued", I went to back to beanstalk > configuration > load balancer and under "secure elb listener" selected HTTPS for protocol and selected "*.domain.tld" for my certificate.

So now when I go to www.domain.tld or domain.tld nothing happens. If I go to https://www.domain.tld it shows the certificate but if I go to https://domain.tld it'll say "connection not private NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" click to continue type message.

Generally speaking I'd like everything to automatically go to https://domain.tld without someone entering in https://

I had to change my environment type to "load balanced" to see the "https/certificate" settings but I want to be able to use https on a "single instance" as well.

Also, when making changes to Route 53 "the DNS stuff" do I need to restart my application?

Answer (score 0):

1) Your Route53 -> EB setup sounds fine.

2) The certificate problem you're seeing when trying to browse to https://domain.tld is because your cert only covers `*.domain.tld`, which does not include `domain.tld`. You can reissue the certificate to cover both.

3) If you want to redirect `http://domain.tld` to `https://domain.tld`, you'll need logic in your web server (apache, nginx, etc) to do that, as DNS does not operate at the protocol level.

4) If you want to use a certificate directly on an EB instance rather than on a load balancer, then you'll have to install the certificate and configure your web server appropriately. If you can afford the expense of keeping the load balancer, that'd be a much easier solution.

5) You shouldn't need to restart your app after making DNS changes.

Comment: Ok, I created a new single certificate with both a wildcard and not. Does EB stand for Elastic Beanstalk? Yes I want the certificate to be directly on it. I think? So you're saying to just use my .htaccess file and redirect everything to https? If I do that can I switch between "single instance" and "load balanced" without making any changes to the beanstalk configuration?

Comment: EB is the usual abbreviation for ElasticBeanstalk.

If you don't want to use an elastic load balancer, then you'll need to configure the web server that's running on your EB instance yourself - and you'll need to do it using `.ebextensions` configuration files as described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html. If you configure your web server manually, your changes will not persist if auto-scaling grows or shrinks your environment.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I was attempting to try this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html but as it turns out my EB application keeps crashing if I switch between "single instance" and "load balanced" :(

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Regardless, I'd recommend you go the load balanced route - it adds a little cost, but setup is much easier.